# Math.pow() not working?

Tags: java, output

this is the code i made, can someone explain me why the output stays 0.0?

(I was trying to make a program that converts binary to decimal, and i know that this can be easily accomplished in java in other ways)

```
    package main;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Class1 {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            int length = input.length();
            double output=0.0;
            String reverse = new StringBuffer(input).reverse().toString();

            for (int i=0; i==length; i+=1){
                switch(reverse.charAt(i)){
                case '1': output = (output + (Math.pow(2, i)));break;
                case '0': break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless `length == 0`, that for loop never executes.

You might well mean something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<length; i+=1){
```

Also, there is no need to use `Math.pow(2, i)` - you can use `1 << i` and keep it all as an integer.

Comment: as a remark: Math.pow() is extremely slow in comparison to bitwise operations. You should avoid it in trivial cases like multiplication by 2 or making a square of a number.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I now unserstand for loops better, but can you explain what you mean by: use 1<<i   and how would it look like then?

Comment: Where currently you have `Math.pow(2, i)`, use `1 << i` instead.